# Setting up SSH on sourcetree - wont PUSH to GitLab - asks for password

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have followed the below instructions to create an SSH key and added it to Gitlab.

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/faq/ (under the heading "How do I set up SSH keys for authentication?")

My changes are being tracked in Sourcetree and I am able to commit but I cannot pull or push without it asking for Authentication.  Every time I add my password  it rejects it but I am able to login direct to Gitlab with the same details.  Am I missing something?

I thought having set up SSH I wouldn't have to authenticate with the username and password as well.  Please see screen shot which shows I have added the SSH key to the Pageant and the authenticate box.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It Could be a number of things:

1. Has your private key been added to Sourcetree? Tools > General > SSH Client Configuration?
2. Has your key been added to the SSH agent? Tools > Launch SSH agent, and is the "Automatically start SSH agent when SourceTree opens" check box ticket
3. Has your private key been added to your profile on GitLab? Profile Settings > SSH Keys
4. Did you clone the GitLab repo using the http link? if so you'll always need to use the details to log in, change that by cloning it with the SSH link. It will be something like git@[domain]:[group]/[project]l.git

Comment: 1.  Yes
2.  When I select Tools > Launch SSH Agent nothing happens.  Nothing Launches so I assume this is causing the issue :/ 
3.  Yes
4.  yes I cloned using the SSH link.

Comment: Ive just realised that the SSH Agent is already open and in the tray.  I had already added the key to this but its disappeared again.

Comment: okay yes that's very likely. There is a similar answer [here] (https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/149890/using-sourcetree-for-windows-with-ssh-keys) I believe the agent is running in the background it just hasn't loaded you key yet. Right click Pageant and view key. If nothing appears then bingo thats your answer.

Comment: Ok, Ive just added the key and ito the Pageant and it still asks for my username and password!  So frustrated.  Please see screen shot Ive added to original question.

Comment: This is a puzzling one, did you add a passphrase when you created your private key, if you shutdown sourcetree and start it back up it should ask for this phrase, sometimes, and as silly as it sounds the window can be hidden on your computer.

Comment: Alternatively if you go to tools > options > authentication  and saved passwords, is there any chance these have changed. If you use LDAP to connect to gitlab have you recently changed your windows password. I know these may sound silly questions but it doesnt hurt to ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93804/discussion-between-antony-and-leetee).

Comment: No it doesn't ask me to ask for a passphrase when i shut down and re open.  I have gone to the autehtication tab in options and deleted the password but now I cannot add another :(

Comment: Sorry I have only just seen your message about continuing in chat.  If you are still available, that would be great!